# - (void)flagsChanged is not called for webview

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have created an editable WebView, and I am trying to write some code in

```
- (void)flagsChanged:(NSEvent *)theEvent
```

to detect, if the user presses the option key.

But if I type anything this method is not called. What might cause this problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that some other method is not getting the event?

In that case, you should send the event to the next responder, that probably will be your method.